# Digest Auth + PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, authentication, digest-authentication

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding authentication using a JQuery Mobile login form and PhoneGap. I need to store the credentials using localStorage and then POST them using Digest Auth. I have the JQuery Mobile Login form but am lost from there. I would appreciate any help I can get! 
Thanks